# Can the Blood Sentinel spell animate an improved familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, familiars

The [Blood Sentinel spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-sentinel) allows turning a statue of a familiar into a living familiar.  Could the caster pick a familiar from the [improved familiar list](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar)?

As the spell is written, it seems like one could use a statue of an improved familiar, but I'm not sure that's the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly none of them that aren’t animals—the material component specifies that you use an *animal* statue, and the overwhelming majority of improved familiars aren’t animals. Only one is: the dire rat.

Otherwise, though, it seems extremely unlikely that even the dire rat was intended to be allowed, because the spell grants the arcane bond feature of a wizard—not that of a wizard who has a particular feat. And without the Improved Familiar feat, that wizard could not have selected any of those familiars.

Comment: The spell doesn't even provide the full range of abilities of the Arcane Bond, pretty much just using the familiar rules to generate stats, and allow communication.